# Lagom-java example for authentication

Tags: playframework, akka, lagom

does there exists any java examples for OAuth with Lagom framework? or a project like [***BootZooka***](https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka#master) but in Java.

I think the documentation of Lagom and very few videos they created are not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

because Lagom uses Play, you should be able to use any [Play Filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters) to implement authentication.  You may even be able to use an [existing one](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/filters).

That being said the lagom developers [have suggested ServiceCall composition](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/lagom-framework/cross$20cutting%7Csort:relevance/lagom-framework/j8vR0cbcV0A/2SmdsRWfDQAJ) over Interceptors or Filters